# unable to retrieve value of list from one method to another

Tags: java

I have ids in a list inside a method called displayid(). I use getters and setters. When try to retrieve the ids from another method Mid(), i am unable to retrieve all values. Only last value is printed. Here is my code

```
void displayId(PrintWriter stdOut, StringResources resources, IPatchBundle group){
    List ids = new ArrayList();
    String MIds=spec.getId();
    ids.add(MIds);
    ar.setMid(ids);
    System.out.println("M Ids of specific group "+MIds);                          
}
```

Output:

```
M Ids of specific group M05632s
M Ids of specific group M05633s
M Ids of specific group M05634s
```

Code:

```
public boolean cmdMId(InputStream stdIn, PrintWriter stdOut, StringResources resources, Arguments args, Object data){
    List ids=new ArrayList();
    ids.add(ar.getMid());
    System.out.println("ar.getMid()=======>"+ar.getM());
    return true;
}
```

Output:
    //Here i need all the three values  but i get only the last value
    ar.getMid()=======>M05634s

Getter setter

```
public List getMid(){
    return mid;
}

public void setMid(List mid){
    this.mid=mid;
}
```

Please help me to solve this

Comment: Could you post a more complete code sample?  In "displayId" ar doesn't seem to be defined.

Comment: You need to show where you call these two methods. You have to pass the same List to both of them and they need to operate ion the same list. (You cna't just give two lists the same name)

Answer (score 0):

What is `spec.getId();` how many Ids does it give?

You have to run the part:

```
String MIds=spec.getId();
ids.add(MIds);
```

for all three Ids, i guess you add only the last one, you can check this buy setting a breakpoint and look how many times do you access the **ids.add()** methode.

Comment: but you call ids.add(ar.getMid()); only once, you have to add all elements in ar using a for loop dont you?